# Why does the scope work like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope, global-variables

This question is a result of a student of mine asking a question about the following code, and I'm honestly completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

When I run this code:

```
#test 2

a = 1

def func2(x):
    x = x + a
    return(x)

print(func2(3))
```

it works perfectly fine. It is able to take the globally-scoped variable a and use its value to perform the calculation and return the value 4.

However, if I change it to this:

```
# test 3

a = 1

def func3(x):
    a = x + a
    return(x)

print(func3(3))
```

I then get an error:

> local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Why do I get this error only when I want to update the value of a within the function to a new value based on its original value? What am I not understanding? I feel like this second piece of code should work fine.

Thanks in advance for any help and insight.

Comment: Personally I always declare `global` on global variables at the top of my function, even when I am only reading them (which strictly is unnecessary).  It is documentary, and to some extent defensive.  One way of looking at it is that global variables are not encouraged in Python because they break encapsulation.  So yes, they are a little bit awkward.  Try to avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 1

def func3(x):
    global a
    a = x + a
    return(x)

print(func3(3))
```

Now it should work.

When you put the statement `a=x+a` inside the function, it creates a new local variable `a` and tries to reference its value(which clearly hasnt been defined before). Thus you have to use `global a` before altering the value of a global variable so that it knows which value to refer to.

**EDIT:**

> The execution of a function introduces a new symbol table used for the
>   local variables of the function. More precisely, all variable
>   assignments in a function store the value in the local symbol table;
>   whereas variable references first look in the local symbol table, then
>   in the local symbol tables of enclosing functions, then in the global
>   symbol table, and finally in the table of built-in names. Thus, global
>   variables cannot be directly assigned a value within a function
>   (unless named in a global statement), although they may be referenced.

Comment: Ah! So very interesting. Thank you so much for the explanation. It makes complete sense now but I must admit is a very strange little caveat!

Comment: If this resolves the issue for you, can you accept the answer so that the poster gets credit and SO sees the question as closed? And yes, this behaviour is one of Python's "gotchas".

Comment: Yes. I was going to but it wouldn't let me select it as the answer that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func3(x):
    a = x + a
    return(x)
```

On the right hand right side of a = x + a (So, x + a), 'x' is passed as variable, where 'a' is not passed as a variable thus an error. 
Without using globals:

```
    a = 1

    def func3(x, a=2):
        a = x + a
        return(x)

    func3(3)
```

Returns: 5